# Rest parameters versus arguments object

Tags: javascript, arguments

How does the `arguments` object differ from the `...args` array created using rest parameters when passing callbacks?  I think of them as interchangeable (aside from the fact that the `arguments` object gets extra info about callee, etc. and isn't a real array) in most use cases.  However, I get different results when passing a callback function.  Why?  Consider the following code:

First code:

```
function logFn(func) {
  return (function logArguments() {
    console.log(arguments);
  })('arguments', 'to', 'inner');
}

logFn('arguments', 'to', 'outer'); // logs ['arguments', 'to', 'inner'] (& callee etc.).
```

Second code:

```
function logFn(func, ...args) {
  return (function logArgs() {
    console.log(args);
  })('arguments', 'to',' inner');
}

logFn('arguments', 'to', 'outer'); // logs ['to', 'outer']
```

Why do these two functions log different values?

Comment: is this an interview question? Because if you are able to write this code on your own you should already know the answer... `args` is hoisted, while `arguments` refers to the function it is currently called at; that's it.

Comment: @smnbbrv Not an interview question—just an area that's been giving me a but of trouble.  Thanks for mentioning hoisting, though, that points me in the right direction for google searches to get me the rest of the way.